*easy* examples of fact in one area of maths proven by a different area of maths
Example (something I raised my hand to ask when I was in secondary school):
How do you know that $\dfrac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$ is necessarily an integer whenever $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers such that $a>b$? This is a problem in elementary number theory.
Though there are other ways to prove it, the best makes use of an observation in combinatorics: given any set $T\subset\{1,2,\ldots,a\}$ of cardinality $b$, the number of permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,a\}$ such that the first $b$ terms of the sequence form the set $T$ is exactly $b!(a-b)!$.
Combinatorics $\to$ elementary number theory
Could you give more examples, suitable for e.g. first-year undergrads or an exceptionally mathematical high school, where you prove a statement in one area of maths by going to a totally different area of maths?
Nothing too advanced: e.g. using complex contours to evaluate a real integral, or using topology to prove properties of the free group.

This is simple! This is just $n \choose k$ and we know all the entries in Pascal's triangle are integers.

The topological problem of comparing shapes (in particular holes) was (partially) solved by algebra. The techniques became so important that we now have algebraic topology.

The fundamental theorem of algebra is probably the most famous and accessible example.

The generating function proof of Binet's formula might fit the bill. The linear-algebraic proof might also work well if they know some  linear algebra.

The use of induction, a subject of number theory, in so many proofs in calculus, topology, and so on and so forth.

Claim: The euclidean metric, $d((x_1,y_1), (x_2, y_2)) = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}$ is in fact a metric. Specifically, it satisfies the triangle inequality:
$$\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2} + \sqrt{(x_3 - x_2)^2 + (y_3 - y_2)^2} \geq \sqrt{(x_3 - x_1)^2 + (y_3 - y_1)^2}$$
Showing that this is true for any three pairs of real numbers purely algebraically is a pain. But if you simply draw the eponymous triangle

Then it becomes immediately clear. Two side lengths of a triangle cannot sum to anything less than the third side, or else they wouldn't be able to span the distance.
